# How to convert network byte to int?

Tags: c#, ord

Reading UDP packet, need to convert a single byte to ordinal value (int).  Or a 4 byte integer value to int.  But the value I am interested is a 0, 1, or 2 - single byte of significance - so don't really need to read all 4 bytes.

```
private async void Button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      using (var TheudpClient = new UdpClient(2237))
      {
         TheudpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,            SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

         var receivedResults = await TheudpClient.ReceiveAsync();

         MsgText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedResults.Buffer);

         MsgTypeStr = MsgText.Substring(11,1);


         MsgTypeInt = (int)MsgTypeStr; // this line blows up...  

     //  MsgTypeInt = int.Parse(MsgTypeStr, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);  // this blows up

     //  MsgTypeInt = Int32.Parse(MsgTypeStr); // this blows up


         richTextBox1.Text = "\nLength: " + MsgText.Length + " Type " + MsgTypeInt.ToString();
         richTextBox1.Text = "\nReceived data: " + MsgText;

        }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         richTextBox1.Text += "\nException: " + ex.Message.ToString();
     }
}
```

Error msg is "Input string was not in a correct format."

I believe the issue is trying to convert a string byte into an int.  In Delphi its easy with the Ord function. I likely need to convert from a char to an int.  Just don't know how to get to char from string.

I am new to C#.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You ask how to convert a "network byte" into an "int", but then you demonstrate converting what you've received to a string. So is the data in text format (i.e. human readable) or in binary format? If the latter then you shouldn't be converting it to a string.

Comment: The data is received and put into a string.  Some of it is readable - that which is ASCII.  Here is the hex representation of the first 16 bytes of the packet received, read with WireShark.  I need to operate on the 12th byte to determine the type of message.  

ab bc db da 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 06.  In this case the 12 byte is 01.  So I need to convert that byte into an int = 1, for further evaluation and processing.

Comment: [This is why you might not want to convert it to string](https://rextester.com/HNVZTN39017), and not process it as a string on the sending machine, if you are. Basically, if a value goes about 0x7F (the end of the ASCII range), you will get 0x3F out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you cast a string to an int, it tries to read the string as if it were a formatted number. But what you want to do is convert the first byte in the string, like this:

```
MsgTypeInt = (int)(MsgText[11]);
```

Caveats: haven't compiled or tried this, and also haven't investigated how many bytes per character is returned from Encoding.ASCII.GetString.

Comment: I agree with @john, you should consider using (int)(received.Buffer[11])) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way to convert byte to integer.

```
class Example {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    byte b = 100;
    int x;
    x = b; // automatic conversion
    System.out.println(b+" "+x);
    }
}
```